# My simulator is going crazy. Simulator scale is different then ViewController and text is corrupted

Tags: ios-simulator

Why?

[image: First try]

And sometimes there's this:
[image: After a few min]

Is it a bug? Is there a fix? I just dragged a button and a textfield to the view controller.

[image: And another bug]

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, few things that come to my mind

- Check if you're using autolayout or 'auto resize subviews'
- Check if you programmatically do any layout
- Check if you're working with portrait/landscape orientation

I doubt it's a bug, such an obvious problem would have been fixed by now

Comment: See my edited post with the second picture. Sometimes the text is half way there on the simulator